# Default Directory for Playground on Xcode

Tags: xcode10

When I create a new Playground with Xcode 10.1 it always defaults to ~/Library/Autosave Information/

Is there any way I can change this?

[image]

Comment: Did symlink helped to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround with `symlink`. Close `XCode` -> enter in terminal:

```
mv ~/Library/Autosave\ Information ~/Library/Autosave\ Information\ Old
ln -s "_desired_folder_path_" ~/Library/Autosave\ Information
```