# Xcode - Change Default Playground Save Location

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

Is there a way to change where Xcode automatically suggests to save a Playground?

Whenever I create one the default location is a folder names "Autosave Information", which is automatically created and of which there are several. I've often "lost" playgrounds in there, and would love for the system to just automatically suggest a predefined path like "./projects/iOS/" without having to worry about the "autosave" folders.

Comment: I have already submitted a bug report to Apple about this, I would suggest that you (and everyone else who understandably is super annoyed by this) should too in order for them to fix it.

Comment: @Alladinian haha, good idea! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57366173/820795